# Error while fetching MySQL data for Google Charts "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

The PHP code throws the error "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        ['Year1', 'CountGiardiaPos', 'CountCryptoPos'],

            <?php
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM sqlAnnualPositives2");

                    if($result){
                        echo "CONNECTED TO CLOUD PRU DATABASE<br>";
                    }
                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                    // output data of each row
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                                    echo "[".$row[Year1].", ".$row[CountGiardiaPos].", ".$row[CountCryptoPos]."],";                                 
                                    }
                                }
            ?>      
        
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1600px; height: 800px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I run the code in a separate PHP file

```
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                echo "['".$row[Year1]."', ".$row[CountGiardiaPos].", ".$row[CountCryptoPos]."],";                                   
                }
            }
```

I get the correct data:

```
['2003', 0, 207],['2005', 0, 29],['2006', 1, 59],['2007', 1, 148],['2008', 1, 109],['2009', 72, 71],['2010', 450, 261],['2011', 1934, 967],['2012', 662, 206],['2013', 627, 487],['2014', 735, 233],['2015', 720, 350],['2016', 855, 503],['2017', 836, 593],['2018', 983, 950],['2019', 920, 508],['2020', 291, 97],
```

Where is the error in the code?

Comment: Where do you connect to the mysql database and execute a query? Is the error message from php or from javascript? If the latter, have you checked the generated output within the page? If yes, did you check if having the 1st value in each data point as string causes the problem (e.g. replace `'2003'` with `2003`)?

Comment: The connection parameters are in a separate PHP file. The error seems to be from the javascript. I have checked the output from the php code and works fine and when pasted the output data, the graph works. But not from the php code. I have also changed '2003' to 2003, with no luck:

Comment: I have now edited the code to show the database connection code.

Comment: You need to check the output of the php script as part of your page. The json object's syntax may be completely off.

Comment: Thanks. Will check the script again. The PHP script output works on its own.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that you're printing `"CONNECTED TO CLOUD PRU DATABASE<br>"` in the middle of your data array, here...

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  // <-- ARRAY STARTS HERE

    ['Year1', 'CountGiardiaPos', 'CountCryptoPos'],

        <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM sqlAnnualPositives2");

                if($result){
                    // PRINTING THIS HERE WILL MESS UP YOUR ARRAY
                    echo "CONNECTED TO CLOUD PRU DATABASE<br>";
                }
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                // output data of each row
                                while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                                echo "[".$row[Year1].", ".$row[CountGiardiaPos].", ".$row[CountCryptoPos]."],";                                 
                                }
                            }
        ?>      
    
    ]);  // <-- ARRAY ENDS HERE
```

but let's back up. first, it is not recommended to manually build json data by concatenating strings and variables.

```
  echo "[".$row[Year1].", ".$row[CountGiardiaPos].", ".$row[CountCryptoPos]."],";
```

instead, build the array in php and use `json_encode` to print it on the page.

```
<?php
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM sqlAnnualPositives2");
  $rows = array();
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // add column headings
    $rows[] = array('Year1', 'CountGiardiaPos', 'CountCryptoPos');

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $rows[] = array($row[Year1], $row[CountGiardiaPos], $row[CountCryptoPos]);
    }
  }
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        // use json_encode to build data table
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1600px; height: 800px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only thing that needed to be changed was the format from string to integer:

`$rows[] = array((int) $row[Year1], (int) $row[CountGiardiaPos], (int) $row[CountCryptoPos]);`